# When I called getBean method to get a @Component bean by Class，a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException occoured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, cglib

MyBean

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestJob implements Job {}
```

MyConfiguration

```
@Bean
public SpringContextUtil springContextUtil() {
    return new SpringContextUtil();
}
```

MyBeanUtilClass

```
@Component
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) throws BeansException {
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

MyMainClass

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I called `SptringContextUtil.getBean(TestJob.class)`, an exception occoured.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.yyy.dayu.service.job.PeentoTaskTestJob' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at com.xxx.yyy.peento.task.util.SpringContextUtil.getBean(SpringContextUtil.java:31) ~[yaochi-peento-task-2022.08.03-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxx.yyy.peento.task.JobConfigListener.tryPutJobBean(JobConfigListener.java:180) ~[yaochi-peento-task-2022.08.03-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxx.yyy.peento.task.JobConfigListener.writeJobs(JobConfigListener.java:151) ~[yaochi-peento-task-2022.08.03-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxx.yyy.peento.task.JobConfigListener.watchConfig(JobConfigListener.java:91) ~[yaochi-peento-task-2022.08.03-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
```

When I debug the code. I find the Spring Factory seems to generate bean by dynamic proxy. So can not find the bean's class. The picture is the `ResolvableType.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> other)` method.
[image]

Comment: YOu have an interface program against the interface else ditch the interface. IN short you should be doing `getBean(Job.class)` not the actual bean.

Comment: But I need to get the bean of specific subclass.

Comment: Which kind of defeats the purpose of an interface. That being said Spring Boot by default enables class proxies (at least if you are on a recent version 2.x) which means the lookup by type should still work. Judging from the image (which is totally unreadable please just post code/errors as text) this is also the case here. So I suspect something else is wrong (like messing with classloaders or something alike).

Comment: ok, I changed the image to the error stack code. I also try to change Job to abstract class, but it does not work, a same error happened.

Comment: I found the reason. Because this project add the spring-boot-devtools dependency and then all class in this project was loaded by restart-classloader. But the class in my Util is loaded by application-classloader, so the parent class of subClass created by cgLib is not the class in my Util.